# Insert new row unless ONE of the values matches another row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert new rows into a MySQL table, but only if one of the values that I'm inserting isn't in a row that's already in the table.

For example, if I'm doing:

```
insert into `mytable` (`id`, `name`) values (10, `Fred`)
```

I want to be able to check to see if any other row in the table already has `name = 'Fred'`. How can this be done?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

What I tried (can't post the exact statement, but here's a representation):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable (`domain`, `id`) 
VALUES ('i.imgur.com', '12gfa')
WHERE '12gfa' not in (
    select id from mytable
)
```

which throws the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE '12gfa' not in ( select id from mytable)' at line 3
```

Comment: Did you try any approach? Did you look at the `if` keyword?

Comment: I tried using `not in` and then doing a select, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `if` keyword

Comment: Can you post your attempt? And any errors it produced? As of the keyword - [it is documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `id` field should be an `autoincrement`, unless it's a foreign key (but I can't assume it from the code you inserted in your question).

In this way you can be sure to have a unique value for `id` for each row.

If it's not the case, you should create a primary key for the table that includes **ALL** the fields you don't want to duplicate and use the `INSERT IGNORE` command.

[Here's a good read](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-handling-duplicates.htm) about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Now that is a nice feature. I wish MSSQL had that one!

Comment: Clarification, if you have a PK and UK, does it apply to both? In other words, if the PK is new, but there is a conflicting UK it will ignore still?

Comment: There's already a `pk` which autoincrements. The `id` is for other purposes. Thanks though, this answer helped me figure out what I was missing. I was already using `INSERT IGNORE` but couldn't figure out how to make sure specific fields were unique. I just marked the appropriate fields as `UNIQUE`, which I wasn't aware existed before.

Comment: Ok, then you got your solution :P

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
INSERT INTO someTable (someField, someOtherField)
VALUES ("someData", "someOtherData")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE someOtherField=VALUES("betterData");
```

This will insert a new row, unless a row already exists with a duplicate key, it will update it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - the data in the duplicate key isn't the same as any of the data in the insert.

Comment: Corrected the statement, mistyped.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE tbl_update (IN id INT, IN nm VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
DECLARE exst INT;
SELECT count(name) INTO exst FROM mytable WHERE name = nm;
IF exst = 0 THEN
     INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(id, name);
END IF;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

or just make an attribute name as `UNIQUE`